# Stretch background images in wordpress row

Tags: wordpress, web, row, frontend

I am trying to make a basic page using wordpress, so i add many raws, and for each raw, i edit and upload a background image.

The problem i have is, why if i increase the font, or make the margin down, the image shrinking. I want the image full sized that row, so whenever i increase the font or add spaces, that will keep or maximize the background image, not shrink it.

This is the page i refer, http://www.zeidny.com/index.php/solutions/

Thanks all for your help,

Answer (score 0):

your code should be

```
<p class="solu1"><span>"I have a message, I&nbsp;want you to hear"</span>
```

instead of

```
<p><span class="solu1">"I have a message, I&nbsp;want you to hear"</span></p>
```

and set min-height for background image and remove margin-bottom style.

Comment: Thanks Vel for your help.

Actually the problem is still persistent.

Whenever i adjust the font, or put more margin, the background image zooms (e.g. to the girl face, even i want the whole image).

Hope i clarify the issue i am facing.

Thanks again for your help,

Comment: Thanks for ur update, but i want to set all of that, in order to make the image full screen of the page, otherwise the image is small, and u ll scroll it via a few scrolls.

Comment: add this style for background image. min-height: 525px;

Comment: please remove margin-bottom:157px; from .solu1 class

Comment: Sorry Vel, how to set min-height for the backrground image?

Comment: .siteorigin-panels-stretch{min-height: 525px; }

Comment: @AOS you didnt add that style in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks vel for ur help...thanks for ur help, but actualy it didn't work, so i tried to revert back trying to adjust as mush as possible, 

Thanks again for your time, and ur help